# Loss of significance $\frac{1-x}{1+x}-\frac{1}{3x+1}$

Tags: numerical-methods

> find a way to overcome $\frac{1-x}{1+x}-\frac{1}{3x+1}$ loss of significance

1. for which values is there loss of significance? is it 0

   to solve it I get need to multiply it by $\frac{\frac{1-x}{1+x}+\frac{1}{3x+1}}{\frac{1-x}{1+x}+\frac{1}{3x+1}}$?

Comment: There is loss of significance near where the two fractions are equal, that is, $x=0$ or $x=1/3$.

Comment: How about $\dfrac{x - 3 x^2}{3 x^2 + 4 x + 1}$?

Comment: @lhf just to use a common denominator?

Answer (score 0):

Just compute the difference, and note that it is equal $-\frac{x}{1+x}$ so it becomes indefinite when $x=-1$.

Comment: Check your computations.